# How do I define a different logger for an imported module in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I'm using [Advanced Python Scheduler](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/index.html#faq) in a Python script.  The main program defines a log by calling logging.basicConfig with the file name of the log that I want.  This log is also set to "DEBUG" as the logging level, since that's what I need at present for my script.

Unfortunately, because logging.basicConfig has been set up in this manner, apscheduler writes its log entries to the same log file.  There are an awful lot of these, especially since I have one scheduled task that runs every minute.

Is there any way to redirect apscheduler's log output to another log file (without changing apscheduler's code) while using my log file for my own script?  I.e. is there a way to change the file name for each module's output within my script?

I tried reading the [module page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) and the HOWTO for logging, but could not find an answer to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the logger level for `apscheduler` to your desired value (e.g. `WARNING` to avoid seeing DEBUG and INFO messages from `apscheduler` like this:

```
logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

You will still get messages for `WARNING` and higher severities. To direct messages from `apscheduler` into a separate file, use

```
aplogger = logging.getLogger('apscheduler')
aplogger.propagate = False
aplogger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)    # or whatever
aphandler = logging.FileHandler(...)  # as per what you want
aplogger.addHandler(aphandler)
```

Ensure the above code is only called once (otherwise you will add multiple `FileHandler` instances - probably not what you want).

Comment: Worked perfectly, at least the setLevel method, which I think will do the job for me (since it's no problem that it logs to the same file as long as it doesn't clog it).  Will try the rest later. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to call  logging.getLogger("apscheduler") and setup its log file in there? see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031557/782168

Comment: Thanks but could you illustrate a bit more?  I'm not sure how to set a file name except through calling basicConfig().

Comment: @ShankarG there *is* documentation about how to set up logging *other* than through `basicConfig()`, see the logging cookbook which is part of the Python docs.