# Is there any way to stop logger in the AWS Iot Python SDK?

Tags: python, iot, aws-iot

In the AWSIoTPythonSDK, in MqttCore.py, there is logger define '''class MqttCore(object):
_logger = logging.getLogger(**name**)'''
Everytime "subscribe timed out" is getting printed in the console, is there any way to forcefully stop the logger of the IoT SDK. I know it is not recommended but i badly needed to stop it forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it recommended, but I did it:

```
sdk_logger = logging.getLogger('AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.protocol.mqtt_core')
sdk_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

you can see here an example that they printed it to a different file:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-iotthingsgraph-camera.py.html

this is a very simple explanation on how logging works in general when you import a module (If you need) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxmzY9soFXg&ab_channel=CoreySchafer

credit: [How do I define a different logger for an imported module in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032967/how-do-i-define-a-different-logger-for-an-imported-module-in-python)

Comment: Will it stop log like "subscribe timed out" or "connect timed out" from displaying into my console?

Comment: because as per SDK "subscribe timed out" is set as error, therefore is setting level for as WARNING is it helpful? is it working?